# Google Cloud Composer with regional kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I'm planning a DR plan in case of zone failures in GCP.

Currently, Composer runs in a single zone. Is there a way to have its Kubernetes cluster regional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, no. [The composer API requires a region when you create the environment but it chooses a single zone within that region to create the cluster](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/create). GKE can clearly support regional and multi-zonal clusters, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to add this functionality to composer